# Kindle ignoring all jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kindle-fire

Does Kindle fire automatically block all JQuery and Javascript?? Settings allow javascript but I can't get the simplest of javascript to fire - not even an alert - can anyone shed any light on the matter?

Comment: Why would a browser default to JS turned off? To force people to use the 1995 version of websites?

Comment: jQuery _is_ JavaScript; surely a Kindle is not going to block jQuery specifically.

Comment: Does it (your site's JS) work on a desktop browser?

Comment: If it's simple JS, posting it in your question may help us help you

Comment: see this on how to enable the javascript http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx3HX0DT8W2SG5J you could be doing something wrong

Comment: The javascript works in all browsers including mobile and non-Kindle tablets. An example of what won't work: $('a').click(function(){ alert 'clicked'; })

Comment: how are you activating your JS/jQuery? is it through a file or embeded or in the header etc please shed some more light on your issue so we can help you because you were very brief. We need to know what your page code looks like to see if there may be an error there or you mightt not be calling it in properly etc...

Comment: Maybe there is an `event.preventDefault();` missing? So that the link simply gets executed? Like: `$('a').click(function(event){ alert 'clicked'; event.preventDefault(); })

Comment: What about `alert("test")` just directly at the top of the script, not in an event handler?

Answer (score 2):

Supposedly there is a setting to turn on JavaScript.

Source: http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx3HX0DT8W2SG5J

Comment: Please note my question notes that JS is already enabled.